# Can't edit block

Tags: blocks

I´m new with Drupal. I started a month ago with Drupal 8. Everything works fine. I had some own custom blocks. Then I added some javascript to one block.

Immediately after that editing of the block or other content was not possible. I can edit nodes, if I open them, there are tabs. But my own block is not possible to edit. If I remove this block, I can edit all other content. If I publish it again, edit button (pen) is missing.

How I can edit my own block again?

The code in the block is taken from here: http://kotisivuapu.suntuubi.com/?cat=194&aid=19&fid=57&mid=57&c=57

I have some code in the block before this script:
some links to
- own folders, like /sites/default/files/picture.gif" 
- internet, www-pages

I see, this is problem with this code and I´ll do it with php.

Comment: It is probably related to the custom javascript code that is included in the block ... post some relevant code perhaps we can understand what is going on.

Comment: Do you see any browser console error ?

Comment: No, not any errors. Just the link is missing.

Comment: Apart from being written in very old syntax the code works and behaves correctly.  I just put it in a block myself and it does not create any problem.  And the edit pen still shows.  Perhaps you did something else wrong pasting the code ? or the the format is limiting js to function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed javascript into a block make sure that your format is not stripping out parts of your code.  Full HTML supplied with core is probably good enough.

Paste the following javascript code just to test that everything works properly.

```
<script>
document.write("test javascript");
</script>
```

And make sure your format is **Full HTML**

[image]
**NOTE:** The recommended way to introduce javascript into a Drupal site would be with a theme or a module as described [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme)

Comment: Yes, with this test piece everything works fine. Problems are there in the copied code.

Comment: I did not have a problem with the test code, copied and pasted exactly as it is.  Perhaps the problem is with the specific theme that you are using ? Try with a different theme enabled/default.

Comment: Thanks for the tests. I´ll do this with php.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

This line: 
document.write("Onnea: " + nimipv + "!");

Shortened like this and everything works: 
document.write("Onnea: " + nimipv + "!");